# Big Query - String Function

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata

I am very new in BigQuery platform, i want to take the following strings 
`SOCKETIOEXCEPTION##APS.COM, NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION##RSJAVA.COM, CLASSCASTEEXCEPTION##MPS.COM`

And get this as a result: `SOCKETIOEXCEPTION, NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION, CLASSCASTEEXCEPTION`

Before `##` characters I want to separate from a given string and then I want to group by number rows available in the above-mentioned tag like `SOCKETIOEXCEPTION, NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION, CLASSCASTEEXCEPTION`

Sample db details

[image]

How do I write this query?

Comment: Clarify wha the output you expect! And have tried anything? Even if it didn't work - show us what it was. Would be great if you can provide simplified example of input data and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT SPLIT(line, '##')[OFFSET(0)] type, COUNT(1) cnt 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY type
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'SOCKETIOEXCEPTION##111' line UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SOCKETIOEXCEPTION##222' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SOCKETIOEXCEPTION##333' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION##444' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION##555' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CLASSCASTEEXCEPTION##666' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CLASSCASTEEXCEPTION##777' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CLASSCASTEEXCEPTION##888' 
)
SELECT SPLIT(line, '##')[OFFSET(0)] type, COUNT(1) cnt 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY type
```

with result

```
Row type                    cnt  
1   SOCKETIOEXCEPTION       3    
2   NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION    2    
3   CLASSCASTEEXCEPTION     3
```